# Русские символы regex в java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Почему получаются разные результаты следующих методов?

```
System.out.println("Путь\\Файл1.html".replaceAll("\\w+\\.\\w+",""));
System.out.println("Path\\File1.html".replaceAll("\\w+\\.\\w+",""));
```

Вывод:

```
Путь\Файл
Path\
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что `\w` в регулярных выражения Java по умолчанию не находит все буквы и цифры Юникода.

Чтобы `\w` находил любые буквы и цифры, используйте флаг [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS), или, внутри шаблона, `(?U)`.

Онлайн-тест [тут](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать следующее

```
val latinOrCyrillic = "[a-zA-Z \\u0400-\\u04FF]"
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете вариант решения, но он не отвечает на вопрос автор "Почему получаются разные результаты следующих методов?" . Подправьте ответ.

Comment: @V.March Я предложил использовать другой подход. Wiktor выше объяснил почему так работает

Comment: Тогда сделайте свой ответ исчерпывающим, чтобы он не зависел от другого ответа(ма-ло ли удалит Wiktor свой ответ). Или просто добавьте свой вариaнт как коментарий к ответу Wiktor, а свой ответ удалите так как в данном виде он не выглядит уместным в качесте ответа. Хотя при  некоторой доработке будет не менее полезен чем ответ Wiktor-a.