# Изменение regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

господа, леди. У меня есть regex выражение - `/^\[\w+\]\[\d\].+$/`. Оно работает замечательно. Использую я его на никнеймах в собственном боте. Он настроен под подобные никнеймы: [LSMC][1] Имя_Фамилия, [SFPD][1] Vladimir_Andreikov.
Со своей задачей он замечательно справляется, но есть некоторая проблемка. Под первый тег в скобочках мне бывают нужны и русские значения по типу [ЛСа][1] Andrey_Andrey. Сам я с regex к сожалению не имею работать, поэтому хотел бы попросить о помощи. Мне необходим regex который будет позволять содержать в первых скобочках значение которое написано русскими или английскими символами, во вторых скобочках должны быть только числа, а после вторых уже что угодно.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вообще "\w" соответсвует всем словообразующим символам, но зачастую они ограниченны латиницей. То есть попадут следующие знаки [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9],[_]. Хотелось бы узнать на каком языке написан ваш код(указывайте пожалуйста в метках). Например в java, это можно исправить, включив флаг  `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`. Подробнее смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680031/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-regex-%D0%B2-java)

Comment: @SelectionForCollection разрабатываю это всё на языке JavaScript. Java в данном случае не подходит :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял по *или* в сообщение, текст ника должен быть либо на русском, либо на английском, для этого используем логическое или

```js
const str = `НагиBATTOR2000ddddd
[Nagibatar][2000]wgeg
[НагиБАТТОР][2000]
[ЁКарный][1001]
[Pro][100]
[ProВася][123]
[Pro100][123]
[Про100][123]
`;
regex = /\[(?:\w+|[а-яё0-9_]+)\]\[\d+\]/mig;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

О регулярном выражении:

```
\[(?:\w+|[а-яё0-9_]+)\]\[\d+\]
```

`(?:\w+|[а-яё0-9_]+)` - не захватываемая группа, где выбираем либо латинские буквы в диапазоне a-z, цифры 0-9 и знак нижнего подчеркивания_, либо кириллицу в диапазоне а-я, цифры 0-9 и знак нижнего подчеркивания_
Использованы ключи регулярного выражения: мультистрока, игнорирования регистра, глобальный поиск

Answer (score 1):

В js `\w+` означает только латинские буквы. Если надо добавить русские, то можно сделать `[\wА-ЯЁа-яё]` или `[A-Za-zА-ЯЁа-яё]`. Если использовать флаг `i`, то можно написать только в одном регистре.

Если позволяет поддержка браузером, то можно разрешить буквы всех языков: `/\p{L}+/u`. Чтобы разрешить только загравные буквы всех языков: `/\p{Lu}+/u`. А для разрешения только кириллических букв: `/\p{sc=Cyrl}+/u`.

Answer (score 0):

Если язык JavaScript, то для обозначения кириллицы предлагается использовать промежуток символов, используя форму `\uhhhh`, где «hhhh» — это значение символа Юникода, записанное в шестнадцатеричной форме. Смотрите пример ниже.

```
var text = 'Образец text на русском языке';
var regex = /[\u0400-\u04FF]+/g;

var match = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match[0]);        // напечатает 'Образец'
console.log(regex.lastIndex); // напечатает '7'

var match2 = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match2[0]);       // напечатает 'на' [не 'text']
console.log(regex.lastIndex); // напечатает '15'
```

Подробнее о регулярных выражениях можете прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
Пример взят из документации. Так что для вашего случая, скорее всего придется использовать промежуток `\u0410-\u044F`

Comment: а `[\wа-я]` нельзя использовать, или что?

Comment: @teran тогда наверно надо добавить флаг `i` ?

Comment: Фигня какая-то.. Русских букв не 255.

Comment: @Qwertiy я в конце ответа уточнил промежуток, указав, что пример кода взят из методички

Comment: @SelectionForCollection, `А-я` - всё равно неправильно. Хотя русскому алфавиту повезло и буквы `Я` и `а` (в отличие от латинских `A` и `z`) идут подряд, потерялись обе `Ёё`. Ну и вообще, зачем писать буквы кодами, когда можно буквами?